# Feathers.js Docker

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I am currently trying to wire up Docker and Feathers.js.  I have followed the tutorial showcased from their site: https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/deploy/docker.html#create-an-app

I can't seem to figure out why I am not able to connect to it outside of the container.  You can see below that the container is indeed running, but when I try to hit any endpoint I am getting a "There was an error connecting to http://localhost:3030/users".  You can view my Dockerfile below in the image (basically a copy from the Feathers site).  End goal is to set this up with React, MongoDB and FeathersJS.  React/Mongo are working well, but I can't get a connection to register for feathers either internally within docker containers, or through localhost as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned in this issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/1772) a previous version of the CLI was generating applications that are binding to the wrong hostname. Make sure that you are using the latest version of `@feathersjs/cli` and your [src/index.js](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/master/src/index.js#L5) is using no hostname and looks like this:

```
const server = app.listen(port);
```